# Error sh: logic: command not found when trying to run logic from python

Tags: python, sh

I need to run this program on some data files. When I type it in the command line it usually works like so:

```
logic ./ case
```

I try to call this from a python script like so:

```
def runLogic(pProtocol):            
    p = 2
    base = os.path.basename(pProtocol[0])
    path = pProtocol[0].rstrip(base)        
    for i in range (1,int(pProtocol[1])+1):
        pAlpha = float(pProtocol[p])
        pl = float(pProtocol[p+1])
        case = 'Einlauf_Lippe_alpha%sdeg_l%smm'%(pAlpha, pl)

# Write mini Python scriptfile
        pyPath = str(pProtocol[0])+'/Einlauf_Lippe_alpha%sdeg_l%smm/'%(pAlpha, pl)
        PyScript = "import os\n\ndef executeLogic():\n    case = '%s'\n    os.system('logic ./ %%s'%%case)\n\nexecuteLogic()"%case 
        pyfile=open(pyPath + 'executeLogic.py', 'w')
        pyfile.write(PyScript)
        pyfile.close()

# Run local PyScript
        os.system('python %sexecuteLogic.py'%pyPath)
# Remove local PyScript
        os.system('rm %sexecuteLogic.py'%pyPath)

        p = p + 2
        i = i + 1
```

In order to create a local python script in the directory where the files to be worked on an then try to execute it. The mini script looks like so:

```
import os

def executeLogic():
    case = 'Einlauf_Lippe_alpha7.5deg_l9.0mm'
    #print 'logic ./ %s'%case
    os.system('logic ./ %s'%case)

executeLogic()
```

When I just type the very line `logic ./ case` into my terminal it works just fine. When I try to start it from python I get the following:

```
sh: logic: command not found
```

Comment: And the `logic` command is in the `$PATH`?

Comment: logic  is in  '/usr/local/quaflow/bin/logic'

Comment: And that is not a standard path. Have you added it to your shells `$PATH` environment variable? Otherwise the shell can't find it.

Comment: And how do I do that?
Is there any other way how I could tell the python where to find the logic?

Comment: The only way is to set the path *before* you call the Python script. You obviously do it for the "manual" command to work. Also, you should know that the `os.system` function invokes the shell to execute the command.

Comment: Sorry for asking all these beginner questions but I just started working with all this stuff about a month ago.

Anyways. So setting this path beforehand, would I do this in the python script?
As far as I knew so far the os.system worked sort of like I just typed that very string into the command line.
What would be the easiest way then, adding logic to the shells environment variable?
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: add it to your path in your .bashrc or  make a symlink

Comment: I created a symlink and now it works swell!

Thanks a lot guys!